# Changing content view insets in collection view messes up UI

Tags: swift, xcode, autolayout, interface-builder

For the messaging part of my app, I have a collection view to display the messages. When the keyboard shows, I change the content and scroll bottom insets to be above the keyboard. When I dismiss the keyboard, and the insets go back to their original position, the text bubbles that are the messages reappear in a very distorted manner

This is my code in the setCollectionViewInstets() function

```
messagesCollectionView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0 , left: 0, bottom: insetFromBottom, right: 0)//setting scroll indicator b4 content inset is much less glitchy
messagesCollectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: insetFromBottom, right: 0)
messagesCollectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

In the keyboard notification selector function, I have this functionality:

```
if isKeyboardShowing{
            print("keyboard showing")
            textViewBottomConstraint.constant = keyboardHeight + initialGapBetweenBottomOfScreenAndTextView!
            setCollectionViewInsets(insetFromBottom: keyboardHeight)
            scrollToBottomOfCollectionView(animated: true)
        }else{
            print("keyboard hiding")
            textViewBottomConstraint.constant = initialGapBetweenBottomOfScreenAndTextView!
            setCollectionViewInsets(insetFromBottom: 0)
        }
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

I expect the chat bubbles to smoothly scroll back in. Due to keyboard animation, the insets change with the same animation as the keyboard. Could this be why, and is there a way around it?

Comment: you can add keyboard handling code in the `UIView` animation block. that brings smoothy transition.

Comment: can you elaborate, perhaps an example?

Comment: my solution atm is to make the collection view much taller than the screen height, but change the top insets to emulate it being at the correct ceiling value

Comment: from my understanding, you are using `collectionview`, when keyboard appears, the chat content has to move above the keyboard. btw collection view itself a scrollview, you no need to increase the height. simply you can pin the `collectionview` (top, leading, bottom, trailing). when keyboard appears you can adjust the bottom constraint constant to the keyboard ht + initial in an animation block.

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/azpeertopeerconnection you can get reference from here